# How to transpose groups of rows into

Tags: r, rows, transpose

I want to transpose groups of rows into groups of columns. But I do not want them on top of each other. I want the result next to each other.
THis is the data:

```
YEAR,RACE,0years,1years,2years
2016,White,c2,d2,e2
2016,Black,c3,d3,e3
2016,Native,c4,d4,e4
2017,White,c5,d5,e5
2017,Black,c6,d6,e6
2017,Native,c7,d7,e7
2018,White,c8,d8,e8
2018,Black,c9,d9,e9
2018,Native,c10,d10,e10
2019,White,c11,d11,e11
2019,Black,c12,d12,e12
2019,Native,c13,d13,e13
2020,White,c14,d14,e14
2020,Black,c15,d15,e15
2020,Native,c16,d16,e16
```

I tried excel, and pivot tables, but the data set is too large. Above is just a summarized example. Below the result I expect.  I have used R but I don't know where to start with this different formatting

```
,0years,0years,0years,1years,1years,1years,2years,2years,2years
,White,Black,Native,White,Black,Native,White,Black,Native
2016,c2,c3,c4,d2,d3,d4,e2,e3,e4
2017,c5,c6,c7,d5,d6,d7,e5,e6,e7
2018,c8,c9,c10,d8,d9,d10,e8,e9,e10
2019,c11,c12,c13,d11,d12,d13,e11,e12,e13
2020,c14,c15,c16,d14,d15,d16,e14,e15,e16
```

Comment: Have a hunt around here for `[r] reshape long to wide` - very probably a dupe since this is just `reshape(df, idvar="YEAR", timevar="RACE", direction="wide")` I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the tidyr option.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  gather(key, value, -(RACE:YEAR)) %>% 
  unite(new_col, key, RACE, sep = "_", remove=T) %>% 
  spread(new_col, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), YEAR ~ RACE, value.var = c("0years", "1years", "2years"))
# YEAR 0years_Black 0years_Native 0years_White 1years_Black 1years_Native 1years_White 2years_Black 2years_Native 2years_White
#1: 2016           c3            c4           c2           d3            d4           d2           e3            e4           e2
#2: 2017           c6            c7           c5           d6            d7           d5           e6            e7           e5
#3: 2018           c9           c10           c8           d9           d10           d8           e9           e10           e8
#4: 2019          c12           c13          c11          d12           d13          d11          e12           e13          e11
#5: 2020          c15           c16          c14          d15           d16          d14          e15           e16          e14
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(YEAR = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L
), RACE = c("White", "Black", "Native", "White", "Black", "Native", 
"White", "Black", "Native", "White", "Black", "Native", "White", 
"Black", "Native"), `0years` = c("c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", 
"c7", "c8", "c9", "c10", "c11", "c12", "c13", "c14", "c15", "c16"
), `1years` = c("d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9", 
"d10", "d11", "d12", "d13", "d14", "d15", "d16"), `2years` = c("e2", 
"e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8", "e9", "e10", "e11", "e12", 
"e13", "e14", "e15", "e16")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: It works great for the summarized example. I have 100 years worth of data. When I try to replace it with the Dataframe it does not work

Comment: @databayou  You can create the `value.var = paste0(0:100, "years"))`